# assigning values to record type variables

Tags: postgresql

I have created type and trying to assign values to the record of that type.
Getting error as

> ERROR: "v_rec.p_text" is not a known variable

Please help me.

```
    do $$
    begin
    create type argtofunction as(
                                        p_text    VARCHAR,
                                        p_arg1    NUMERIC,
                                        p_arg2    VARCHAR,
                                        p_arg3    VARCHAR);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN duplicate_object THEN null;
    END $$; 
                                    do $$
    begin
        CREATE DOMAIN argtofunction_v as argtofunction;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN duplicate_object THEN null;
    END $$;


    create or replace  function cust_func() RETURNS void AS 
        $$
        declare
        v_rec argtofunction_v;
    begin
    v_rec.p_text    := 'start';
    v_rec.p_arg1    :=1122;
    v_rec.p_arg2    :='CUST1;
    v_rec.p_arg3    :='PUNE';

    perform sale_function(v_rec);
    end $$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Afaik you cannot create a domain based on a custom composite type - this should raise an error. You can assign a value to a composite variable this way: `v_rec := ('start', 1122, 'CUST1', 'PUNE');`

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I tried as you suggested. Now the function is created.
But while executing giving the error.

SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: malformed array literal: "(start,1122,CUST1,PUNE)"
  Detail: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
  
Please help me.

Comment: What is the type of the parameter of `sale_function()`?

Comment: The parameter for sale_function is p_argtofunction which is domain type of argtofunction_v 
sale_function(p_argtofunction argtofunction_v)

even I connect the call of sale_function getting same error.
--perform sale_function(v_rec);

Thanks

Comment: The information provided does not allow error location, it is probably in the body of `sale_function()`

Comment: I tried by commenting the call of the function sale_function() still same error.

Comment: The problem is that you have no arrays in the provided code.